# $f'(x;y)=0$ for every $x$ in an open convex set and for every vector $y$ ; then to show $f$ is constant on $S$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, normed-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a map , $S$ be an open convex set in $\mathbb R^n$ such that for every $x \in S$ and $y \in \mathbb R^n$ , $f'(x;y)$ exists and equals $0$ ; then how to show that $f$ is constant on $S$ ?

(where $f'(x;y)=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+hy)-f(x)}{h} $ )

Comment: What do $f(x+hy)$ or $f(x)$ even mean for a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @bartgol : $h \in \mathbb R$ is a scalar and $y \in \mathbb R^n$ is a vector ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I misread the question.

Comment: @user251257 : $f$ is convex where from ?

Comment: oh my bad. i read it wrong.

Comment: consider the function $g(t) = f(x+th)$. then $g'$ is constant zero and thus $g$ is constant. now argue that each such $g$ is the same constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contradiction. Assume $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Define $y=x_2-x_1$, $g(t) = f(x_1+ty)$. You know that $g'(t)=f'(x_1+ty;y)=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Lagrange theorem gives $g(1)-g(0) = g'(s)(1-0)$, with $s\in[0,1]$. But $g'(s)=0$ and $g(1)-g(0)=f(x_2)-f(x_1)\neq 0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing hf'(x,y)=f(x+hy)-f (x) then as you know f'(x,y) always exists and is 0 make an argument for why f (x+epsilon×y)=f (x) for some epsilon.